# How to execute other directory feature files in karate

Tags: java, cucumber, karate, gherkin

I had a situation where i am working in home.feature and need to call return.feature and gets the data. And internally return.feature is calling data.feature and collects all the data from it.

```
Source
 directory1
   home.feature
 directory2
   return.feature
   data.feature
```

I have written * def response = call read('classpath:source/directory2/return.feature') in home.feature.
while calling this line, it is picking up the correct feature file, but while executing return.feature, it throws error while calling data.feature(javascript evaluation failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException).

Please guide what could i do in home.feature file, as i dont have access to change in directory2.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `this:` prefix: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files

So this should work when you are inside `return.feature`

```
* call read('this:data.feature')
```